# Check whether a point inside or outside a circle (implementation with structs only)

Tags: c, struct, scanf

First, I've given a task to implement this with structs only.

I need to check whether a point is inside/outside a circle.

Input: Coordinates of the point, center of circle, radius.

Output: Is the point inside/outside the circle.

Well, I need to use the distance formula `d = sqrt( (x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 )` and then check if it is bigger/smaller/equals to the radius.

I know the logic, but I fail with struct's syntax. can you guys help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
}Point;

typedef struct {
    Point center;
    float radius;
}Circle;

int main()
{
    Point Coordinates;
    Coordinates.x = 0; //Is this initialization necessary?
    Coordinates.y = 0; //Is this initialization necessary?
    Circle insideCircle;
    float distance;
    printf("Please enter the coordinates of your point: ");
    scanf("%f %f", Coordinates.x, Coordinates.y); //after input, throws error.
    printf("Please enter your center coordinate and your radius: "); 
    scanf("%f %f", insideCircle.radius, insideCircle.center.x, insideCircle.center.y);
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f", Coordinates.x, Coordinates.y, insideCircle.radius, insideCircle.center.x, insideCircle.center.y);

//More code for checking if distance > or < or = to radius to be added.
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using sqrt() when it's not necessary, and I would compare d² with (x1-x2)² + (y1-y2)². This would be more efficient if you need to test if a lot of points are inside the circle because you will need to compute d² only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `scanf()`, you need to pass the address of the variables as the argument to the supplied conversion specifiers, like

```
scanf("%f %f", &(Coordinates.x), &(Coordinates.y));
               ^                 ^
```

and for the other usage(s).

That said, it is essential that you check the return value of `scanf()` call to ensure the success.

Comment: To all variables except string sir.?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS if you meant _string type_ (not literal) in previous comment, then, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*i think this piece of code will help you*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        float x;
        float y;
}Point;

typedef struct {
        Point center;
        float radius;
}Circle;

int main()
{
        Point Coordinates;
        Coordinates.x = 0;
        Coordinates.y = 0;
        Circle insideCircle;
        float distance;
        printf("Please enter the coordinates of your point: ");
        scanf("%f %f", &(Coordinates.x), &(Coordinates.y) ); //scanf requires &
        printf("Please enter your center coordinate and your radius: ");
        scanf("%f %f %f", &(insideCircle.radius), &(insideCircle.center.x), &(insideCircle.center.y) );//scanf requires &
        printf("%f %f %f %f %f", Coordinates.x, Coordinates.y, insideCircle.radius, insideCircle.center.x, insideCircle.center.y);

        //More code for checking if distance > or < or = to radius to be added.
}
```